# DOMDocument - get node XML without adding namespaces

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

Test XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<testroot xmlns:abc="http://abc">
    <testA>testNodeText</testA>
</testroot>
```

Test code:

```
$xml = file_get_contents('test.xml');
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);

var_dump(
  $dom->C14N(),
  $dom->getElementsByTagName('testA')->item(0)->C14N()
);
```

Result:

```
// 1
<testroot xmlns:abc="http://abc">\n
    <testA>testNodeText</testA>\n
</testroot>

// 2
<testA xmlns:abc="http://abc">testNodeText</testA>
```

When getting content of node DOMDocument is adding namespace. Problem is that `testA` node is not equal to same `testA` node. This has huge impact when creating hash value from parts of XML.
I just can't get node from XML and calculate hash from it, because there are namespaces moved from document root.

Any ideas how I can get node content from DOMDocument to get it as it is in original document?

Comment: Does `$dom->saveXML($dom->getElementsByTagName('testA')->item(0))` do what your after?

Comment: You cannot guarantee that a document element will be presented in the same way after parsing it. The two nodes are equal in that they mean the same thing to an XML parser. If you want to calculate a hash on something, do it on the contents of the node, not the XML representation of the node.